# Making a star pyramid. The number base of the pyramid is incorrect

Tags: c#, logic

[image]

The problem is that once pourposley entering the wrong input which is the the positive number "4", it says try again, which is correct.

But once I try again and enter 5 which is the correct input because it is a odd number which is an integer, it creates a pyramid, with the base of 4 stars rather than 5 stars.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            bool loop = true;
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the number which is an integer and a odd number");
                int userinput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());//converts the string into an integer 
                validation(userinput);//checks if the userinput conditions are met
                pyramid(userinput);//if conditions are meet userinput will be inserted into the PYRAMID parameters
                loop = false;
               
            } while (loop == true);

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the number which is an integer and a odd number again");
            int newuserinput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());//Asks the user to input another number
            validation(newuserinput);//checks if conditions are meet
            pyramid(newuserinput);//if meet put the new userinput into the parameters 
            static int validation(int a)
            {
                
                int counter = 0;
                while (counter == 0) //counter is used to loop to keep and asking and checking 
                {
                    if (a > 0 && a % 2 != 0)//checks if the userinput is an odd number integer
                    {
                        return a;//returns the BOOL value true if it meets the conditions
                        counter += 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Try again ");//If it doesnt meet the conditions it will ask again
                        int again = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                        if (again > 0 && again % 2 != 0)//checks if the condition is met again
                        {
                           
                            return again;//returns true if conditions met 
                            counter += 1;
                        }

                    }
                }
                return 0;

            }

            static void pyramid(int number)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) //For loop to make sure the other for lopps run inside of it n number of times
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < number - i; j++) //the loop is used to fill in the blanks of the console and as the varible j keeps increaseing the number will also decrease
                    {
                        Console.Write(" ");
                    }
                    for (int k = 0; k <= i; k++)//outputs the astrix n amount of times the user inputs 
                    {
                        Console.Write("* ");

                    }
                    Console.ReadLine();//makes a space for each for loop looped


                }
            }
```

I suspect that either my validation subroutine is not returning the proper value after the try again statement

Or that my DO and While loop is messed up.

Could you please help me fix this problem and tell me the solution? And expalin what is wrong

Comment: It would be pretty easy to narrow down the issue. Avoid all the issues with input and such and just call `pyramid(5)`. Is the output correct? If it isn't then you need to fix that before worrying about input and such. If it is correct then you've narrowed down the issue to how you're handling input and can focus on that.

Comment: One thing to think about is if `validation` returns a value why aren't you using it?

Comment: Yes ive tried that it works if I enter the desired input correctly but once I purposely enter the wrong input followed up by the correct input it outputs the wrong inoput as the number of base rather than the correct one.  And the subroutine validation does does return 2 values and I am using both?

Comment: Okay, so inside `pyramid` print the value of `number`. Does it match what you expected? Can you explain how you are using the return value from `validation`? I don't see it. You might read through your comments inside the function as well. Does it return a `BOOL` or the value that was input? This code `return again;//returns true if conditions met` returns the value that was input but the comment says something else. Not really an issue since it always returns in the `if` or `else`, but code written after `return` is meaningless. `counter += 1;` will never execute.

Comment: Is it also that in my validation my else loop inside my validation doesn't seem to be working as returning a new value is not being returned.  How would I fix this?

Comment: Try `userinput = validation(userinput);` You need to assign the return value to something or it is lost.

Comment: where do I put this

Comment: Where you are calling `validation` now.

Comment: omg thanks for that, that works.  But why does this line of code needed?  because I had a return value for the else loop?

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a look at an arbitrary line within the pyramid:

```
    *
   * *
  * * * <- let's have a look at this line
 * * * *
* * * * *
```

if pyramid has height `height` the `i`th (`i = 1..heiht`) string consist of indent and `i` asterisks spearated by spaces:

```
"  * * *"
| ||   |
| | body : i asterisks joined by spaces
| |
indent of size height - i
```

To consruct indent we can create all spaces string: `new string(' ', heigth - i)`

To construct body we repeat `*` `i` times and join them by  :

```
using System.Linq;

...

private static IEnumerable<string> Pyramid(int height) {
  for (int i = 1; i <= height; ++i) 
    yield return new string(' ', height - i) + 
                 string.Join(" ", Enumerable.Repeat('*', i));
}
```

Finally, we print:

```
int n = 7;

foreach (string line in Pyramid(n))
  Console.WriteLine(line);
```

Output ([fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OQZ2Re)):

```
      *
     * *
    * * *
   * * * *
  * * * * *
 * * * * * *
* * * * * * *
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help but I already am able to fix this step.  I just have a problem with my valididation subroutine where in the else loop it would not return the "again" value but only the "a" value.  I done know why that is the case.